# Parent Table View Updation From child fxml

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

Scenario:
I have a parent window called `EditClientDeatils.fxm`l and have a `TableView` on this.     I am editing these row result by creating another window named `UserDetails.fxml` and populating the row data to this FXML fields, now after editing from my second window , If I save I need to update the parent table with latest data.I tried something like below and not refreshing the table at all. But when I debugged my table list is updated with latest Data and not showing that in Window.
So How can I update my table view from different controller ?

In Child Window I am loading the parent like this.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("EditClientDetails.fxml"));
                EditClientDetailsController fooController = (EditClientDetailsController) fxmlLoader.getController();
                try {
                    fxmlLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewUserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

And in my parent class initialize method having below code:

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

```
    fNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientFirstName"));
    lNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientLastName"));
    addressCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientAddress"));
    mobileCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientMobileNumber"));
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientEmailID"));
    catagoryCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("clientTypeCode"));
    genderCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<AtUser, String>("gender"));

    editSaveAction.setSortable(false);

    editSaveAction.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<AtUser, Boolean>, 
            ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<AtUser, Boolean> p) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
        }
    });

     editSaveAction.setCellFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn<AtUser, Boolean>, TableCell<AtUser, Boolean>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<AtUser, Boolean> call(TableColumn<AtUser, Boolean> p) {
            return new ClientButtonCell(customerTable);
        }

    });
    // Add filtered data to the table

    customerTable.setItems(filteredData);

    // Listen for text changes in the filter text field
    filterField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                String oldValue, String newValue) {

            updateFilteredData();
        }
    });

}
```

When I am debugging

```
customerTable.setItems(filteredData);
```

this `filteredData` is containing my required data but not coming on Window.
please point out if I missed anything.

Comment: that is to say its not refreshing?

Comment: Yes..its not refreshing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found this work arround it, to force it to refresh.

```
table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```

After modifing the table items list.

Comment: can you post your code so that I can take a look at it?
The whole thing I mean